# Why passing arguments to function via inline assembly isn't consistent?

Tags: winapi, assembly, visual-c++, x86, calling-convention

I have a jump from original function to my hook, which runs assembly that executes a function. I'm trying to pass arguments from the original function to the function **mWSARecv**.

Here's how I do it:

```
void mWSARecv(LPWSABUF lpBuffers)
{
    std::cout << "WSARecv: " << lpBuffers->buf << " Len: " << lpBuffers->len << std::endl;
}

__declspec(naked) int hookWSARecv() // Original -> Here
{
    __asm
    {
        pushad;
        pushfd;

        push[ebp + 0x24];
        call mWSARecv;

        popfd;
        popad;

        jmp WSARecvTramp;
    }
}
```

I then save registers and flags. Push the desired argument [ebp + 0x24] and call the function which outputs those. It works once, but the next time it causes an execption.

The original function calling convention is **__stdcall**.

First jump:

[image]

Assembly hook:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `mWSARecv` is CDECL calling convention the caller has to cleanup the stack. You push 4 bytes with `push[ebp + 0x24];` so you'd have to add add 4 to esp after. Maybe place `add esp, 4` after the `call mWSARecv`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you! If mWSARecv would be STDCALL, It should auto cleanup the stack right? In that case adding 4, wouldn't be necessary? Also, could you please explain me, why do I have to add 4 to stack pointer?

Comment: In _STDCALL_ the function you call cleans up the stack of the parameters passed. In _CDECL_ the responsibility falls to the person calling the function.  If `mWSARecv` is _CDECL_  the 4 bytes pushed by push[ebp + 0x24];` have to be cleaned up by you (with something like `add esp, 4`). Failure to do the add of 4 to _ESP_ (in this case) means when mWSARecv returns it will then execute `popfd` and `popad` but everything is shifted by 4 on the stack meaning everything that restored by those 2 instructions is corrupt.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks a lot, making much more sense now! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default (without overriding the calling convention) the following is [*CDECL*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) calling convention:

```
void mWSARecv(LPWSABUF lpBuffers)
{
    std::cout << "WSARecv: " << lpBuffers->buf << " Len: " << lpBuffers->len << std::endl;
}
```

Per the calling convention, the MSDN documentation says:

> Stack-maintenance responsibility - **Calling function** pops the arguments from the stack.

This is different from [*STDCALL*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) which has this rule for argument cleanup:

> Stack-maintenance responsibility - **Called function** pops its own arguments from the stack.

With this in mind the issue in your code is in `hookWSARecv` in these lines:

```
    push[ebp + 0x24];
    call mWSARecv;

    popfd;
```

Because `mWSARecv` is *CDECL* the parameters you push have to be cleaned up after the call. Failure to do this means that when `popfd` and subsequent stack operations occur they will all be restored from the wrong place on the stack. In this case to cleanup the stack of the one 4-byte parameter pushed you need to add 4 to *ESP* after the call. The fix would look like:

```
    push[ebp + 0x24];
    call mWSARecv;
    add esp, 4;
    popfd;
```

Comment: Thanks again for this, appreciate! I have one more question though, could be that [ebp + 0x24] location of argument isn't always the same?

Comment: @J.Doe The location of the argument will always be on the stack before the return address pushed by the _CA:LL_ instruction itself. The physical address where the argument is pushed on the stack can change depending on the program itself. It is possible I may not have completely understood your new question though.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. The issue occuring was also cause the argument offset wasn't always the same. One time its 0x24, the other time 0x23. Would you know how could I detect such changes? Thanks!

Comment: You are using the parent function's `ebp` rather than setting up your own stack frame.  There's not necessarily any reason for that to be consistent, at the very least it will depend on what function is calling WSARecv.  Read the argument relative to `esp` instead, that will be consistent.